# Python multiprocessing queue.get with timeout vs sleep

Tags: python, timeout, multiprocessing, sleep

I can't find any documentation on python's queue get with timeout: get([block[, timeout]]) whereas there is good documentation on python's time.sleep() at http://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-time-sleep-pause-wait-sleep-stop-your-code/.

I've used the linux time to time a loop of 5, 500 and 5000 over both with a period of 100 ms and they both seem similar.

Snippet 1: with queue timeout

```
while True:
    try:
        if self._queue.get(True,period) == '!STOP!: break
    except:
        # Queue.Empty session, keep going
        -- do stuff here --
```

Snippet 2: With time sleep

```
while True:
    try:
        if self._queue.get_nowait() == '!STOP!: break
    except:
        # Queue.Empty session, keep going
        -- do stuff here --
        time.sleep(period)
```

Snippet 1 is preferred because instead of sleeping, and then checking the poison pill queue, it 'sleeps' checking the queue. Of course it is a pretty moot point, since the period will normally only be between 0.100 and 0.500 secs but I wan't to make sure there isn't something in the queue.get that I'm missing.

Comment: What's your question? Did you read the documentation for the [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) method? What's unclear about the description?

Comment: I did but there is no description of what underlying methods are used in get. in time.sleep, unix gettimeofday is used (where available). I don't need rt but want as close as possible which from the docs, I can get from time.sleep but with get() I don't know what's being used and if there is something going on under the hood that may preempt causing a empty esception to be thrown early or late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the first option is a better choice because instead of just unconditionally sleeping for `period`, then checking to see if anything is in the queue, and then sleeping again, you're actively waiting for something to be `put` into the queue for the entire `period`, and then just briefly doing something other than waiting for the `'!STOP!'` to arrive. There's no hidden gotchas; `get_nowait` is internally using `time.time()` + `period` to decide how long to wait 1) to be able to acquire the internal lock on the queue, and 2)  for something to actually be in the queue to get. Here's the relevant code from `multprocessing/queues.py`:

```
    if block:
        deadline = time.time() + timeout
    if not self._rlock.acquire(block, timeout): # Waits for up to `timeout` to get the lock
        raise Empty # raise empty if it didn't get it
    try:
        if block:
            timeout = deadline - time.time()
            if timeout < 0 or not self._poll(timeout): # Once it has the lock, waits for however much time is left before `deadline` to something to arrive
                raise Empty
        elif not self._poll():
            raise Empty
        res = self._recv()
        self._sem.release()
        return res 
    finally:
        self._rlock.release()
```

Comment: guess I should have gone to the code before asking :)